# Get value from SweetAlert2 select box?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have the following code... which is used for a sweet alert text box

```
swal({
  title: 'Select an Item',
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: listOfItemsForSelectBox,
  inputPlaceholder: 'Select country',
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValidator: function (value) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (value != null) {
        resolve()
      }
    })
  }
}).then(function (result) {
  swal({
    type: 'success',
    html: 'You selected: ' + result
  })
})
```

For some reason, it just returns "true" in the 'You selected' part...

I want to get the item's id.

Answer (score 7):

Example from [swal2 official docs](https://sweetalert2.github.io) works fine. Check your `listOfItemsForSelectBox`, perhaps it has some wrong format.

```js
swal({
  title: 'Select Ukraine',
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: {
    'SRB': 'Serbia',
    'UKR': 'Ukraine',
    'HRV': 'Croatia'
  },
  inputPlaceholder: 'Select country',
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValidator: function (value) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (value === 'UKR') {
        resolve()
      } else {
        reject('You need to select Ukraine :)')
      }
    })
  }
}).then(function (result) {
  swal({
    type: 'success',
    html: 'You selected: ' + result
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.5/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.5/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it was informative. I do have a question in regards combination of the label and input options. Can you please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65566877/align-label-and-select-dropdown-in-the-same-row-in-the-sweetalert-2

Answer (score 3):

```
}).then(function (result) {
  swal({
    type: 'success',
    html: 'You selected: ' + result
  })
})
```

should be

```
}).then(function (result) {
  swal({
    type: 'success',
    html: 'You selected: ' + result.value
  })
})
```

if you output 'result' to a console you will see all the data that is associated with the 'result' variable. (i.e. console.log(result))